# VB.Net refer to function/private sub itself

Tags: vb.net, function

Is there anyway refer to function or private sub itself without affect to another ?
Using 'Me' operator does not works for me because refer to the main Window

```
Private Function comboclean() As Boolean
    ???.items.clear()
return nothing
End function

Private Sub nAdult_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   nAdult.SelectedIndexChanged
    comboclean()
End Sub

Private Sub nJunior_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nJunior.SelectedIndexChanged
    comboclean()
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a clarification, which framework are you working in? Asp.net, winforms or WPF ?

Comment: So whenever a user changes the selected item in your combobox, you want to clear all the items?  That doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: @Tim I know, I am confused at what his use case is.

Answer (score 3):

Is something like this what you are looking for ? I am assuming you are wanting to clear the calling `ComboBox`, I created a function that takes the `SelectedIndexChanged` sender object and passes it to the function.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    comboclean(DirectCast(sender, ComboBox))
End Sub

Private Function comboclean(combo As ComboBox) As Boolean
    combo.Items.Clear()
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks you ! It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this... the one function clears out all of the combo boxes.

```
Private Sub comboclean()
    nAdult.items.clear()
    nJunior.items.clear()
End Sub
```

Otherwise you would need to pass the control you want to clear to the subroutine.  Something like this may work.

```
Private Sub comboclean(TheList as Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)
    TheList.items.clear()
End Sub

Private Sub nAdult_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   nAdult.SelectedIndexChanged
    comboclean(sender)
End Sub

Private Sub nJunior_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nJunior.SelectedIndexChanged
    comboclean(sender)
End Sub
```